# Hot Keys in Sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

So I am trying to access the Add and Subtract option for when sculpting in Blender. But my Ctrl hotkey for switching between the two isn't working, how do I change the hotkey for that option?

Comment: Im not sure, because I'm not at my computer, but look around in the user perfs tabs there might be something there

Comment: *File > User Preferences > Input > 3D View > Sculpt*